# How can I enlarge both text if 2 annotations are requested in ImageMagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

My codes are written like this.
It insert "text_here" to the uploaded image file.
This text is in white color with black shadow in behind.
In spite of the fact I'm stating **-pointsize 15** twice, it larges only the

```
has_attached_file :user_avatar,
    :styles => {
    :thumb=> "100x100>",
    :small  => "400x400>" }, 
     :convert_options => {
     :small => ' -gravity south -stroke "#000C" -strokewidth 2 -annotate 0 " text_here! " -pointsize 15 -stroke none -fill white -annotate 0 " text_here! " -pointsize 15' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a/ I do not completly know what you want to do but put the -pointsize before the -annotate.

b/ If one is a black shadow why do you need two differnt point sizes.

c/ Why are you using stroke ?

Try this:

```
 :small => ' -gravity south  -pointsize 15 -fill black -annotate +0+0 " text_here! " -fill white -annotate +2+2 " text_here! "' }
```